# Recursive map over array using extension method

Tags: swift, recursion, extension-methods

I have a collection of `LayoutElement` that I receive from an API.

For simplicity sake, imagine it contains 2 properties -

`String` or `[LayoutElement]`

I'd like to iterate over this collection and if the value has children, loop over the children recursively, returning the `LayoutElement` that contains a `String`

Essentially I should end up with a `[LayoutElement]` that contains only the elements that have a `String` value.

As this will be used in multiple places, I thought I could create an extension on `Array` where the element is `LayoutElement` but I am unsure how best to do this in the case of `element.children`.

```swift
import UIKit


struct LayoutElement {
  let children: [LayoutElement]?
  let text: String?
}


let data = [
  LayoutElement(children: nil, text: "First Text Element"),
  LayoutElement(children: [
    LayoutElement(children: nil, text: "Second Text Element"),
    LayoutElement(children: nil, text: "Third Text Element"),
    LayoutElement(children: [
      LayoutElement(children: nil, text: "Fourth Text Element"),
    ], text: nil)
  ], text: nil),
]



extension Array where Element == LayoutElement {
  var asLayout: [LayoutElement] {
    return map { element in
      if let children = element.children {
        // ???
      } else {
        return element
      }
    }
  }
}

let output = data.asLayout

print(output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't figure how to do it because you chose the wrong higher-order function. You should use [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap), not `map`.

`map` transforms each array element into another element, but `flatMap` can transform each element into *several* other elements. You should use `flatMap` when the resulting array has a different size than the starting array, which is the case here. `data` has 2 elements, while `output` should have 4 elements. `map` can never increase the number of elements.

```
  var asLayout: [LayoutElement] {
    return flatMap { element -> [LayoutElement] in
      // for each element, we return the array of elements into which we want to transform it
      if let children = element.children {
        return children.asLayout
      } else {
        return [element] // we don't want to transform it, so we return an array containing only "element"
      }
    }
  }
```

Returning `children.asLayout` should do the job.

Or in one line:

```
var asLayout: [LayoutElement] {
    flatMap { $0.children?.asLayout ?? [$0] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by capturing your collection in a local array before returning the result

```swift
extension Array where Element == LayoutElement {
  var asLayout: [LayoutElement] {
    var flatten: [LayoutElement] = []
    forEach { item in
      if let children = item.children {
        children.asLayout.forEach { child in
          flatten.append(child)
        }
      } else {
        flatten.append(item)
      }
    }

    return flatten
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a temporary array to collect all the results:

```
extension Array where Element == LayoutElement {
    var asLayout: [LayoutElement] {
        var result = [LayoutElement]()
        forEach {
            if let children = $0.children {
                result.append(contentsOf: children.asLayout)
            } else if $0.text != nil {
                result.append($0)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the use of ` result.append(contentsOf: children.asLayout)` - that completely slipped my mind, it makes the syntax much sleeker